# Converting Swift block to Objective-C block

Tags: objective-c, xcode, swift, closures

In Swift, I have created a closure method (I think):

```
func firstMove(action: UIAlertAction!) {
        if action.title == "Yes" {
            currentPlayer = "X"
        } else {
            currentPlayer = "0"
        }
```

That I pass into this UIAlertAction method:

```
let optionToStartController = UIAlertController(title: "", message: "Do you want first move?", preferredStyle: .Alert)
            optionToStartController.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Yes", style: .Default, handler: firstMove))
```

How can I convert both the closure and method to Objective-C?

I have tried doing:

```
- (void)firstMove:(UIAlertAction*)action
{
  if ([action.title isEqual: @"Yes"]) {
    _currentPlayer = 'X';
} else {
    _currentPlayer = 'O';
 }
}
```

And passing it like this:

```
UIAlertController *optionToStartController = [UIAlertController alertControllerWithTitle:@"" message:@"Do you want first move?" preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
[optionToStartController addAction:[UIAlertAction actionWithTitle:@"Yes" style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault handler: firstMove]];
```

Comment: What is it that you want to do? Show a `UIAlert` when you press a `UIButton`? Be clear on what exactly it is that you want to do.

Comment: Yes, that's what I wan to do.

Comment: Why do you want to do that? Just add a bridging header and you can use Swift and Objective-C in the same project!

Answer (score 0):

You may be looking for blocks, the objective-C rough equivalent of closures.  I'm not quite sure what you're trying to accomplish, but the following code defines block firstMove and how it is passed and called from method addAction.

```
void(^firstMove)(int) = ^(int x){
    NSLog(@"print y: %d", x);
};

[self addAction:firstMove];
```

...

```
-(void)addAction:(void(^)(int))y{
    y(5);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can see the example. It should work properly.

```
UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                 alertControllerWithTitle:@"Question"
                                 message:@"Do you want first move?"
                                 preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];
    //First button
   UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                        actionWithTitle:@"YES"
                        style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                        handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                        {
//Actions if the user press this button
//Dismiss the alertController. It's preferred to be in all actions.
                            [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
_currentPlayer = @"X";

                        }];

//Second Button
   UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                            actionWithTitle:@"NO"
                           style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                           handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                           {
//Actions if the user press this button
//Dismiss the alertController. It's preferred to be in all actions.
                               [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];
_currentPlayer = @"O";

                           }];
    //Add the actions to the alertController
   [alert addAction:ok];
   [alert addAction:cancel];


//present the alertController on the device. If you are writing this in the viewController, you can use self.view, if you are in UIView, then just self
   [self.view presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];
```

Comment: `UIAlertView` is deprecated. Why should we use `UIAlertView` with delegates when we can use `UIAlertController` with blocks?